# How to create very large Json object in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a json file like this:

```
{
    "students": [
        {
            "name": "Jack",
            "age": "12",
            "class": "8",
            "start_date": "2021-01-01",
            "score": {
                "Eng": "90",
                "Math": "90",
                "History": "91",
                "Art": "80"
            },
            "friend": {},
            "talents": [
                "dance"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "school": [
        {
            "city": "LA",
            "state": "CA",
            "country": "US",
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to modify this file and add new students' info into it
like this: (Add more similar json objects into students with minimum change)

```
{
    "students": [
        {
            "name": "Jack",
            "age": "12",
            "class": "8",
            "start_date": "2021-01-01",
            "score": {
                "Eng": "90",
                "Math": "90",
                "History": "91",
                "Art": "80"
            },
            "friend": {},
            "talents": [
                "dance"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "David",
            "age": "12",
            "class": "8",
            "start_date": "2021-02-01",
            "score": {
                "Eng": "92",
                "Math": "90",
                "History": "95",
                "Art": "70"
            },
            "friend": {},
            "talents": [
                "skate"
            ]
        },
        ... ...
    ],
    "school": [
        {
            "city": "LA",
            "state": "CA",
            "country": "US",
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to do this in large scale? Since I need to append >1000 new students.
And since this is a large json and only do minimum change, so I don't want specify each key and value for >1000 times.

Comment: Can you not just serialize a whole list of objects or a dict and then save that json string output to a file? Also share your code, since we aint doing it from scratch for you.

Comment: Can't you populate the structure using a dict() and then dump it as JSON?

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code. I guess that this can even be done with search and replace of a good text editor.

Comment: From where will you get the students to add?